# Errors on build a small c program with library pdfium

Tags: windows, testing, build, pdfium

I am trying to build the init.c with pdfium, to test if works.
I have on dir at desktop, file init.c, pdfium.lib  and public directory with header files of pdfium.
init.c code is

```
    #include <fpdfview.h>
  int main() {
  FPDF_LIBRARY_CONFIG config;
  config.version = 2;
  config.m_pUserFontPaths = NULL;
  config.m_pIsolate = NULL;
  config.m_v8EmbedderSlot = 0;
  FPDF_InitLibraryWithConfig(&config);
  FPDF_DestroyLibrary();
  return 0;
}
```

Opening on Windows cmd type ...

```
 set PDF_LIBS="-lpdfium -lfpdfapi -lfxge -lfpdfdoc -lfxcrt -lfx_agg -lfxcodec -lfx_lpng -lfx_libopenjpeg -lfx_lcms2 -lfx_freetype -ljpeg -lfdrm -lpwl -lbigint -lformfiller -ljavascript -lfxedit"
set PDF_DIR=pdfium
```

Then trying to build with ...

```
 g++ -I $PDF_DIR/public -o init init.c -L $PDF_DIR/out/Debug -lstdc++ $PDF_LIBS
```

I am taking errors ...

```
>g++ -I $PDF_DIR/public -o init init.c -L $PDF_DIR/out/Debug -lstdc++ $PDF_LIBS
```

g++: error: $PDF_LIBS: No such file or directory

Any idea why? I have take instructions from https://pdfium.googlesource.com/pdfium/+/master/docs/getting-started.md
Thank you
Jim

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use bash (and other Linux shells') variable expansion syntax in Windows' shell, that's not going to work. Windows uses `%VAR%` and not `$VAR`.

So, either use the right syntax, like this...

```
g++ -I %PDF_DIR%/public -o init init.c -L %PDF_DIR%/out/Debug -lstdc++ %PDF_LIBS%
```

...or use a Linux shell. As a developer, you probably already have Git installed, so you can just use the Git bash for that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have wrong, init file is c file, so i must use gcc.

Comment: I have move pdfium.lib to libs directory, an now i am trying the ... gcc -Ipdfium -o init -Llibs -lpdfium. Finally i am taking C:/MinGW-w64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):crt0_c.c:(.text.startup+0x2e): undefined reference to `WinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status